# Cannot find the property name of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular2-routing

```
      <ion-content padding>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label fixed>Username</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" value="" (ngModel)]="userData.username"></ion-input> </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label fixed>Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" (ngModel)]="userData.password"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <button ion-button block color="primary" (click)="login()">Login</button>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
```

this is login.html code when I am accessing y clicking the button it is throwing
Cannot find the property name of undefined

```
login()
{
this.authServiceProvider.postData(this.userData,'login').then((result) => {
     this.responseData = result;
     console.log(this.responseData);
     localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
     this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
}, 
(err) => 
{
         // Error log
});
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you may need to check if your variables are properly set (ie typo or casing issues?) you are trying to set a property by name, in this case it is most likely the 'userData' field of a 'localStorage' object.

Comment: Your error talks about the `name` property, and there's no name in your code, only username. Could you please post your full error stack so that we can help you ?

Answer (score 0):

You re missing **`[`** in all ngModel

```
<ion-input type="text" value="" [(ngModel)]="userData.username"></ion-input> </ion-item>
```

Comment: try  [(ngModel)]="userData?.username"

Comment: Safe navigation operator can't be used with two way binding directly

Comment: `[ngModel]="userData?.username" (ngModelChange)="userData && userData.name=$event"`